django gunicorn "Error handling request (no URI read)"
I'm running a django application using gunicorn inside a docker container, but I'm encountering an error on request. The application fails with the following error log:
[2024-11-13 18:50:11 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Error handling request (no URI read)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 133, in handle
    req = next(parser)
  ...
SystemExit: 1

But the request is eventually processed and a response is provided, but it takes a time.
Here is mt dockerfile:
FROM python:3.13.0-alpine3.20

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache jq python3-dev build-base gcc jpeg-dev zlib-dev libpq-dev

COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN jq -r '.default | to_entries[] | .key + .value.version ' Pipfile.lock > requirements.txt && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./src/media:/app/src/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

  db:
    image: postgres:17.0-alpine3.20
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres_data:

I'm starting gunicorn with this command:
gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

I just had this too... brand new Docker container, a "500" was shown in the browser window for this one (i.e. "the request is eventually processed and a response is provided" did not apply for me. Docker on Mac;
